# Installing Pre-Release R 3.3.2 on Linux Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: r, linux, installation

I am trying to download and install the Econometrics package to R. I am using R version 3.3.2, and ubuntu 16.10 (I spent hours today trying to do this, including updating to 16.10 from 16.04 LTS). current base for R is 3.3.1, with prelease as 3.3.2.

I downloaded R-latest.tar.gz from the https://cran.rstudio.com/src/base-prerelease/R-latest.tar.gz ,then extracted it, changed directory to the given folder where it was extracted.
ran 
./configure 
hit enter, which ran through a bunch of "checking" and returned

"configure: error: --with-x=yes (default) and X11 headers/libs are not available"

next, I read to "make" or "make && make install" but this isnt doing anything.

"make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop."

and this is what came from the install folder, so I have no idea. tried to reinstall from sudo-apt get install, but this re installed the version 3.3.1, which I previously had on here (I spent a while trying to update from 3.3.1 to 3.3.2, which wasnt successful, so tried to uninstall and reinstall.)

any advice will be tremendoussssslllyyyy appreciated.

thanks

DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let's decompose these issues

- your upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10 has nothing to do with the *R* upgrade, so I won't mention it any further
- the Debian and Ubuntu distributions have arguably the best support for new R among distros
- I have been maintaining R for Debian for something like fifteen years. My Debian builds get "ported" (ie rebuilt) for Ubuntu by Michael Rutter and are generally available the next day -- via CRAN (see the README)
- R 3.3.2 comes out Monday, you will have a new Ubuntu version by Tuesday or Wednesday at the latest. For several Ubuntu releases, so it does not matter which Ubuntu version you run
- Similarly, Johannes "rebuilds" for Debian into a repo available via CRAN
- I have already made two prebuilds of R 3.3.2 for Debian -- but these we generally do not "port" but just wait.
- Lastly there is a dedicated mailng list r-sig-debian where these matters get detailed and questions answered.  Go there.
- If you still must build from source, you are free to do so. We even provide stanza with our build files. But I do not have time to walk you through each error. What you ran into is something elementary (ie "missing  build-depends")
- Finally, if you wish, you can also get Docker containers under the 'rocker' (for "R on Rocker") tag.

**Edit:**  As for the econometrics package (URL?), *every* package on CRAN will install *with the current release of R* so you are chasing ghosts and making your own life difficult by insisting on *an unreleased version of R*.  Just learn how to take advantage of the Ubuntu repo at CRAN, use R 3.3.1 now and 3.3.2 within days.  With zero effort or trouble.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will definitely wait, and it's something I will be more aware of in the future. Bad timing on my part!   Here is the link to the package https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Econometrics . html    . When I tried installing in R thru install.packages("Econometrics") it said not available for your version.   Sorry, I'm on phone and can't get exact message.

Comment: No problem, and welcome to StackOverflow. If this was helpful, feel free to accept (== click on 'tick' sign only you see as you asked the question) and/or upvote (== click on up-arrow).

Comment: You are trying to install a _Task View_ as a package.  That will not work.  With any version of R, so upgrading to an unreleased version is, how can I put this politely ;-), no quite the right diagnosis of the underlying issue...